# Is there a way to modify the python code for inception-v3 in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow

Right now I'm using inception-v3 based on the tutorial provided by google.
TO retrain and test it I use the command:

```
bazel build tensorflow/examples/label_image:label_image && \
bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image \
--graph=/tmp/output_graph.pb --labels=/tmp/output_labels.txt \
--output_layer=final_result \
--image=$HOME/flower_photos/daisy/21652746_cc379e0eea_m.jpg
```

But now I need to modify some parts of the code and since I'm using bazel to build I don't really know if it is possible or not and where the code actually is.
Is there a way to use it as plain Python code and run it as a regular python script?

Comment: the code is wherever points BUILD target :label_image specified in tensorflow/examples/label_image/BUILD

Comment: BUILD is pointing to a code in C++, is it possible to have the same code in Python?

Comment: no. This is c++ example. There are many more using inception-v3, some of which are python, like image_retraining/retrain.py.

Comment: I've used the retrain but it seems that it cannot be used for testing, right? I mean, a single image test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That model is unfortunately written in C++.

But there's a very nice inception implementation in the `tensorflow/models` repo here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception

It also includes detailed instructions on how to train and evaluate the model.
The evaluation step is described in
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception#how-to-evaluate
and is written in Python.
The evaluation script is [`inception_eval.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/inception_eval.py).

Answer (score 1):

A python script (written in tensorflow keras) for the models

- VGG16
- VGG19
- ResNet50
- Inception v3
- CRNN for music tagging

can be found [here](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models)